# Monotonic functions bijectively mapping rational numbers to $n$-adic rationals (numbers having finite expansions in base $n$)

Tags: rational-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

The [Minkowski's question-mark function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function) is a monotonic bijective function from rational numbers to numbers with finite binary representations. For which natural numbers $n$ is there a monotonic one-to-one correspondence between the set of rational numbers and the set of finite base-$n$ numbers?